# Can not read math formula when edit content in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor, fckeditor

I'm using math formula in ckeditor, when I insert new content by textarea, it can read math formula, but if I edit this content, it seem can not read and display text formula as before..

this is my source:

```
<head>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['\\(','\\)']]}});</script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/standard/ckeditor.js">   </script>
</head>

<body>
<table border="0" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <span >Question Code : <%=id_q%>&nbsp;-&nbsp;<%=valid_types%>&nbsp;(Number presented : <%=make_cnt%>)</span>
        <table border="0">
        <tr>
        <td width="640" height="650">
            <textarea name="ir1" id="ir1" rows="1" cols="10" style="width:580px; height:600px; min-width:400px; min-height:50px; display:none;"></textarea>                     
            <script>
                var ir1 = CKEDITOR.replace('ir1', {                                     
                extraPlugins: 'mathjax,video,font,justify,preview,colorbutton,panelbutton',
                mathJaxLib: 'https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.6-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML'
                });
                CKFinder.setupCKEditor(ir1, 'libraries/ckfinder/');
            </script>
        </td>           
    </tr>
</table>   
</body>
```

This is result when I cliked edit button for content:
[image]

How to display correct mathjax in ckeditor when edit content? thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser dev console? Also try turning off any 3rd-party plugins and then check if it still does not work.

Comment: Hi @f1ames: I have check dev console, it seem it is not error, I don't understand 3rd-party plugin, can you tell more about this ?

Comment: By 3rd-party plugins I mean all plugins not developed by CKSource (here is the list of all plugins developed by CKSource - https://ckeditor.com/cke4/users/CKSource). One more question, could you provide an input/data which is set in CKEditor (or which is present in textarea when CKEditor is initialized)?

Comment: Did you get an answer to this question?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to move the MathJax-script to the bottom of your head tag like this:

```
    <head>            
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
        <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['\\(','\\)']]}});</script>     
    </head>
```

To ensure the code has access to the MathJax namespace.